# Вывести товары на страницу каталога Opencart

Tags: opencart

Имеется сайт на Opencart. Как можно выводить товары на страницу "Каталог"? Сейчас они выводятся только в соответствующие категории.

Comment: Пожалуйста, задавайте более развёрнутые вопросы. В данном случае хотя бы уточните версию opencart

Comment: Страница каталог в дефолтном шаблоне не присутствует, это допил либо кастомный шаблон. Соответственно ответ не может быть дан на общих условиях особенностей функционирования opencart.